Google Play Integrity API prepareIntegrityToken hangs without response
We're using Google Play Integrity API and sometimes (when trying to create a Standard Token) the call to prepareIntegrityToken hangs without any respone for no apparent reason.
Here is the code:
standardIntegrityManager = IntegrityManagerFactory.createStandard(context);

standardIntegrityManager.prepareIntegrityToken(
StandardIntegrityManager
.PrepareIntegrityTokenRequest
.builder()
.setCloudProjectNumber(CLOUD_PROJECT_NUMBER)
.build())
.addOnSuccessListener(response -> { 
// code
});

The problem is the success listener is never fired (as well as any other listeners). Log:
StandardIntegrity : warmUpIntegrityToken(XXXXXXXXXXXX)
StandardIntegrity : Already connected to the service.
StandardIntegrity : Waiting to bind to the service

I'm unable to pinpoint the conditions of this issue. It works for some time, then it doesn't, sometimes all it takes is to restart the phone and it stops working. Retrying has no effect.
What's interesting, Play Integrity API Checker (by Nikolas Spiridakis) app hangs while checking device integrity as well. So I believe it's not the issue with exceeding quotas or something.
What could be the problem?
Tried contacting Google support, but so far nothing.

Same issue here!
Try use VPN to access google's service, that might be help. It works for me, since google's service is blocked in China.
lol
